# Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate) in java 11.0.9

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services

I tried to connecting java 11.0.9 to MySQL 5.6 connector, but am getting the below error in the server, but in local same code it's working fine

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:336)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:325)
... 22 more INFO    2021-08-19 12:26:14,581 [grpc-default-executor-5]

details :

Mysql driver version:8.0.21
java:11.0.9

I am using AWS ec2 Linux server, I am facing the problem only in server

Comment: Check what it's expecting with:  


"openssl s_client -connect ip:port"

Comment: where I need to check this,its in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution for this, explicitly add the connection properties in code ex:properties.setProperty("useSSL", "false");

Comment: Not using SSL results in cleartext, I think...Fine when you're connecting on 127.0.0.1 but I would not suggest doing that over a network connection.

Comment: 5.6 and 5.7 not supported SSL